# How to preserve a config.json file when reinstalling electron app?

Tags: electron, config, electron-builder

I have an electron app that uses a static config.json file to hold individual client connections. When we reinstall the the app, say to a newer version, the file gets wiped in c:\programs{appname}. Is it possible to retain this static file on reinstall somehow? We're using electron-builder for the build.

I have been attempting to edit the nsis settings in the package.json file, our current set up is:

```json
"nsis": {
  "oneClick": false,
  "perMachine": true,
  "artifactName": "${productName} Setup.${ext}",
  "uninstallDisplayName": "${productName}"
}
```

Comment: Instead of your `config.json` file being stored in the `c:\programs\{appname}` directory, could it be stored in the users application directory found by using `app.getPath('userData);`? EG: `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\{appname}`. See [app.getPath(name)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpathname) for more information. That way, you won't lose it every time your application updates.

Comment: Not an option for our use case unfortunately, the machines are shared and the same config needs to be available for every user,

Comment: Ok. Is the config a static file or a living breathing changing file?